# $\displaystyle k^{th}$ derivative of a Gaussian function with zero mean

Tags: derivatives, hypergeometric-function

The gaussian function is:
$$f(x,\mu,\sigma)=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}\exp\left(-\dfrac{(x-\mu)^2}{\sigma^2}\right)$$
Putting $\mu=0$, we can get the $\displaystyle k^{th}$ derivative of this function.
It is:
$$\dfrac{d^k}{dx^k}f(x,\sigma)=\dfrac{2^k\left(\left(-\dfrac{x}{\sigma^2}\right)^kU\left(-\dfrac{k}{2},\dfrac{1}{2},\dfrac{x^2}{\sigma^2}\right)\right)}{\exp\left(\dfrac{x^2}{\sigma^2}\right)\left(\dfrac{x^2}{\sigma^2}\right)^{k/2}}$$
where $U(a,b,x)$ is the confluent hypergeometric function of th second kind. I'm stuck in proving the previous formula. How can it be proven? Thanks

Comment: There is a relation to [Hermite polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials#Relation_to_confluent_hypergeometric_functions). Maybe you can start with pluggin in: $H_{n}(x) = 2^n\,U\left(-\frac{n}{2},\frac{1}{2},x^2\right)$...

Comment: In its second appearance $\sigma^{2}$ should be replaced by $2\sigma^{2}$.

Comment: Are you sure about the $\left(\dfrac{x}{\sigma^2}\right)^k$ in the numerator and $\left(\dfrac{x^2}{\sigma^2}\right)^k$ in the denominator?

Comment: @draks...I corrected the typo. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

In general $$f\left(x,\mu,\sigma\right)=\sigma^{-1}\phi\left(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}\right)$$
where $\phi\left(x\right)=f\left(x,0,1\right)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^{2}}$.
Consequently: $$f^{\left(n\right)}\left(x,\mu,\sigma\right)=\sigma^{-n}\phi^{\left(n\right)}\left(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}\right)$$
This equality allows you to concentrate on the $\phi^{\left(n\right)}$.

The annoying parameters are placed outside.